# How to pass web assembly c++ objects to javascript callback with Emscripten

Tags: javascript, c++, webassembly, emscripten, embind

I have c++ code compiled to web assembly using Emscripten. Using Emscripten it is possible to expose c++ objects to javascript via one of the binders - Embind or WebIdl-binder. I am using Embind. The binding works very well when we want to return c++ object to javascript as a return value for web assembly call or just create them directly.

In my case my web assembly code needs to call javascript back in order to get some data and then resume the web assembly flow. In this case in the javascript callback from the c++ I need to pass a struct in which the js code should fill the data. However when I do this instead of the c++ object in the js callback, I receive a number. I guess this number is the address of the c++ object, but not the object itself.

My question is - am I missing something or it is not possible to pass c++ objects as arguments for a javascript callback. Here is the sample code:

C++

```
#include "emscripten/bind.h"

using emscripten::class_;

class TestClass
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;

    int GetA() { return a; }
    int GetB() { return b; }
};


extern "C" {
  extern void testCallback(TestClass testClass);
}

void testFunction() {
    TestClass testClass;
    testClass.a = 5;
    testClass.b = 10;

    std::cout << "Calling js callback" << std::endl;
    testCallback(testClass);
    std::cout << "Js callback called!" << std::endl;
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(test_project)
{
    class_<TestClass>("TestClass")
        .constructor()
        .function("GetB", &TestClass::GetB)
        .function("GetA", &TestClass::GetA);

    emscripten::function("testFunction", &testFunction);
};
```

JS:

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
    testCallback: function(testClass) {
        console.log(testClass);        // prints 65496
        console.log(testClass.GetA()); // error: TypeError: testClass.GetA is not a function
    }
});
```